# Htaccess redirect subdirectory extension and query string

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-301

I have url like this http://www.example.com/subdir/Subcontent?QUERY=420501 i want to redirect it to http://www.example.com/subcontent.html?QUERY=420501 so if Subcontent is dynamic in url then it will change first letter of Subcontent to small and redirect to final url http://www.example.com/subcontent.html?QUERY=420501

I have tried with this

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} QUERY=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.html
RewriteRule ^subdir/(.*)$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

But it does not seems to work i think sequence is not proper of conditions cangetting clueless on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this `RewriteMap` in Apache or vhost server config:

```
RewriteMap lc int:tolower
```

Also you have an extra condition, use this rule to redirect and lowercase your URLs:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)QUERY=([0-9]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^subdir/([\w-]+)/?$ /${lc:$1}.html [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: we are very close url is changing now to http://www.example.com/Subcontent.html?SSAID=420501 but issue is S is capital it needs to be small can we also make it so there could be extra s in subcontent so the final url will be http://www.example.com/subcontents.html?SSAID=420501 thanks anubhava you are the men!

Comment: This is the final version that worked for me RewriteRule ^subdir/[sU](.*?)/?$ /u$1s.html [L,NC,R=301]

Comment: Stack overflow is changing [s U] to superuser if  there is no space between s and U then it change it to superuser just wondering if we can make it little bit more better so for example if Subcontent is dynamic and first letter is capital like in url http://www.example.com/subdir/Subcontent?QUERY=420501 then it can automatically lowercase first letter of Subcontent ?

Comment: Yep we have a dedicated ubuntu 16.04 server with full root access